# Resistor Calculation formula

Tags: resistors

I am very new to electronics,my question may seem silly for you guys but kindly clarify the doubt.

Consider a 12V @1A power supply and R1=R2=10K. What will be the output for the two scenarios?

What is the formula to calculate these parameters?

[image]

What is the formula to calculate these parameters?

Comment: Depends on whatever the load is

Answer (score 1):

Unloaded, both circuits output 12 volts. Loaded, the first one can only supply 1.2 mA into a short circuit. The second circuit can virtually supply the full load current of the supply.

If you want to calculate "parameters" then it would be highly useful for you to state what parameters you mean.

Answer (score 0):

We are not here to do your homework for you.

However, look up *Thevenin* and *Norton* equivalent circuits.

Hint: In this case, start by converting both circuits to their Thevenin equivalent.